# Memra fixed in or used as a substitude

Tags: words, commentaries, targumin

Could someone explain to me as to why most Targums fix in the (Aramaic) word 'Memra into a lot of verses, or use it as a substitude for other words written in the Tenach; what's the idea and meaning behind this? Why interpret the Tenach in such a way?

Answer (score 1):

The Ramban deals with this at length in Bareshis 46:1. He brings that the Rambam in Moreh Nevuchim part 1 chapter 27 says things like this are to distance physicality from Hashem. The Ramban then asks many questions on this approach. He finishes by saying cryptically that the idea is "known in kabbalah".